# ¿Como manipulo control (Label, Text, Button etc) en C#?

Tags: c#

Tengo un código en donde según el resultado string de números le asigno al Label/Etiqueta un color correspondiente, Pero me gustaria reducir ese codigo:

[image: Ejemplo 1]

a un código reducido(entendiendo la segunda linea no es correcta ):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestra el codigo como texto, no como imagen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la propiedad [`Controls`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx) del form para referenciar controles por nombre:

```
this.Controls["lblNumero" + resultado].ForeColor = // ...
```

Toma en cuenta que la instancia que te devuelve es de tipo `Control`, de modo que si necesitas trabajar con una propiedad específica a `Label`, tendrías que hacer un cast explícito. Pero en este caso, solo necesitas acceso a la propiedad `ForeColor` que es una propiedad común a todos los controles, así que el cast no es necesario.

Comment: Gracias, muy precisa y clara tu respuesta. Tenga su like buen samaritano